Make Errbit write logs
I've just set up an Errbit server in a Docker container. It seems to work well, except I'm not getting any emails. So I thought, it's a Rails project, go to the log directory and look at production.log to see whether the email is getting rendered and sent correctly. And neither directory nor file are there.
I found that there is an environment variable ERRBIT_LOG_LOCATION that is either STDOUT(which is the default value) or Syslog::Logger. The default is STDOUT. Does this mean the server output is simply thrown away?
Then I set this to "Syslog::Logger" (the line in my docker-compose.yml file is
- ERRBIT_LOG_LOCATION=Syslog::Logger

just like that), and the container did pick it up after a reboot. Some research said that this means errbit now uses syslogger for logging, so I ought so see something in /var/log/syslog. However, there isn't anything.
I have an nginx running to redirect the domain to the right port (8080). So I checked if there was anything in the nginx logs. Again, nothing. They are empty.
The self.errbit app inside the errbit app tab when I'm logged into my errbit instance is also not present, meaning that the value of the env variable doesn't seem to be a problem.
Personally, I'd like it if errbit logged in the same way as every other Rails app. Or at least, I'd like some kind of logging at all. Is there anything I can do about it?

If you'd like Errbit to log like an ordinary Rails application, you can specify the log file using ERRBIT_LOG_LOCATION:
ERRBIT_LOG_LOCATION=./log/production.log (or absolute path)

"No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /app/log/production.log (Errno::ENOENT)". However, both dir and file exist, I included them in the build. If I don't set this env var, the container starts up correctly and I can see that dir and file exist. However, the file remains empty. ---Btw, there's also an env var RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT. I tried setting it to false in the docker-compose file. No result.

Errno::ENOENT is an error from a system call (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html). The Linux kernel is telling you that file does not exist. It really doesn't exist (from the perspective of your Ruby process). It sounds like you're using docker. You can verify this by using docker exec or attach to explore the filesystem inside your container.

Of course, the whole setup is running in Docker, this is clearly mentioned in my question :-/ The container is running, and if I docker exec into it I can see both the dir and the file. Btw, why does the comment tool remove my attempt to reference the previous commenter?

All right. I'm not happy with this because I really don't understand what happens. I've now set the loglevel to debug, set the loglocation as you mentioned AND defined a volume to point to the log. Now finally production.log is getting written to.  I'll accept your answer as soon as I know what is going on.

Got it. Stupid me. Pulled the wrong image and wondered why changes don't happen.
